NextJs app creating Hangs up at devDependency install
Creating a new NextJs project
npx create-next-app@latest
I give a name to the project, use all defaults and the installation hangs up installing devDeps
I don't understand why this is happening, any ideas?
node v
v20.6.0
npx v
9.4.0

Upgrade both node and npx then retry

This didn't seem to do anything different, what I've noticed is that it seems like the devDeps install does not complete, it just hangs up.  But if i force out of the process and open the project up again it seems like everything is there.  I have to install my deps again 'npm i' but I can't figure if anything else is missing.
